# Any lecture notes or easy explanation of Holton's Meteorology?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, resource-recommendations, atmospheric-science, meteorology

I am struggling with understanding Holton's Dynamic Meteorology. Any lecture notes based on the book with easy explanations will help.

Comment: Do you mean this book https://archive.org/details/introductiontody48holt ?

Comment: Yes. This is the book.

Comment: What actually you don't understand in this book?

Comment: "Since except at the equator and poles the
centripetal acceleration has a component directed poleward along the horizontal
surface of the earth (i.e., along a surface of constant geopotential), there must be a
net horizontal force directed poleward along the horizontal to sustain the horizontal
component of the centripetal acceleration".  I don't understand how the centripetal accelaration has poleward component.

Comment: Is this only question or may be you have several of them?  Can you add all questions to your post?

Comment: Actually, the language of the book is hard to me. I have faced problems before upto this topic, but could manage to understand. But this one i can't grasp, how the centripetal accelaration, which is inward towards the axis of rotation,has poleward component. I can't visualize it.

Comment: Did you read about the centripetal acceleration, for instance, on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centripetal_force ?